# Predict UID for new user within a specific range from /etc/passwd

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

I have to create users with UID in a range from 8000 to 9000 in /etc/passwd. Is there a way to predict the next UID to use with a commmand line.

I know the command below gives me the UID to use after the last UID present in the passwd file :

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN {maxuid=0;} {if ($3 > maxuid) maxuid=$3;} END {print maxuid+1;}' /etc/passwd
```

What do I have to change in the command line in order to get the next UID to use within the range 8000 - 9000 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i would try something like  `if ($3+0 > maxuid && $3+0 >= 8000 && $3+0 <=9000)` note that it can return `1`

Comment: @user2728615, please do mention details in your question clearly so that we could help you on same.

Answer (score 0):

This will fill the first available ID even if there are holes open in the used IDs (e.g. 8000 and 8002 are used but 8001 isn't and so should be the next ID chosen to be used):

```
awk -F: '
    { used[$3] }
    END {
        avail = 0
        for (i=8000; i<=9000; i++) {
            if ( !(i in used) ) {
                avail = i
                break
            }
        }
        print avail
    }
' /etc/passwd
```